# Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea, jvm, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a project with Java and Kotlin, which I am able to successfully run and build. However, when I open the project in IntelliJ, I see the same error in many of the project files.

The error is "Cannot access class 'java.lang.String'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies"

See the error in the image attached:
[image]

---

Another example of an error occurs when initializing a [Kotlin MultiPlatform Mobile](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mobile/getting-started.html) project:

```
cannot access 'java.lang.Object' which is a supertype of 'org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.RepositoryHandler'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
```

---

What is the source of this error? How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried to run "File | Invalidate caches"? If it doesn't help please share build.gradle to check used dependencies.

Comment: I'd suspect that your project/module has no JDK configured. Open Project Structure and look for Project SDK or Module SDK

Comment: @AndreyBreslav, JDK and SDK were connected as usual. Projects on Java worked stably.
The problem was solved after a FULL reinstallation of the ideal.

Comment: Maybe counter-intuitively, under Project Structure > Modules > yourmodule > Dependencies, "Module SDK" needs to be suitable Java SDK, _not_ the Kotlin SDK. (That solved a similar issue for me.)

Comment: Im using two flavours and when i moved one package out of the main into the flavours folder i started getting this error. no fix yet

Comment: I had this issue, because I added both the Java SDK and the Kotlin SDK to the project. I only needed the Java SDK, when I removed Kotlin and restarted this fixed the issue.

Comment: In this my case  class package name that used was wrong, And just fixed package name

Comment: Had the same issue after reinstalling the open jdk. Resolved by setting the correct version in File > Project Structure > Project > Project SDK (it was still set to the old outdated invalid path)

Comment: +invalidate caches and restart solves it

Comment: I'm using Android Studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1 patch 3.  When I created my KMM project it defaults to the embedded SDK.  To fix it I had to switch to liberica-11 JDK.  I'm sure other JDKs will fix the issue too, but that worked for me.  Try changing your selected JDK under Gradle Settings.

Comment: @Raphael ""Module SDK" needs to be suitable Java SDK, not the Kotlin SDK. " Its working thank you very much

Answer (score 27):

If your project is set with a JDK, then probably IDE (Intellij) does not have JDK set but your built application could run just fine with the required JVM. Open the project structure window (ctrl + shift + alt +s) and select the java version you created your project with.

Answer (score 11):

In our project we encountered this because we added the same directory to both production and the test sources.

```
sourceSets {
  main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin/'
  main.java.srcDirs += 'build/generated/source/protos/main/java'
  test.java.srcDirs += 'src/test/kotlin/'
  test.java.srcDirs += 'build/generated/source/protos/main/java'
}
```

Removing the duplicate from the test sources fixed the problem.

```
sourceSets {
  main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin/'
  main.java.srcDirs += 'build/generated/source/protos/main/java'
  test.java.srcDirs += 'src/test/kotlin/'
}
```