# IntelliJ wrongly complains in Gradle Kotlin-DSL that it cannot find "java.lang.String"

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin

In the following build.gradle.kts (Kotlin DSL) script, IntelliJ marks the line with "mainClassName" red and complains about: "Cannot access class 'java.lang.String'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies."

Using `./gradlew clean assemble` on the command line, everything works.

Can anybody give me a hint how to fix that?

IntelliJ is latest version 2019.1-community.

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.3.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-03-28 09:09:23 UTC
Revision:     f2fae6ba563cfb772c8bc35d31e43c59a5b620c3

Kotlin:       1.3.21
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018
JVM:          11.0.2 (Oracle Corporation 11.0.2+9)
OS:           Linux 4.9.0-8-amd64 amd64
```

```
plugins {
    java
    application
}

group = "de.lathspell"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile("junit", "junit", "4.12")
}

configure<JavaPluginConvention> {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

configure<ApplicationPluginConvention> {
    mainClassName = "de.lathspell.App"
}
```

Downloadable at https://github.com/lathspell/gradle_test/tree/master/java-gradle-kts in commit 5e5da7b.

Comment: `wrongly complains`. No. If it complains it's legitimate complain. The fact it works when triggered manually only means it works when triggered manually. Nothing more.

Comment: What research have you tried? I found this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50304263/check-your-module-classpath-for-missing-or-conflicting-dependencies) where the original poster answered their own similar question in the comments

Comment: @anon: My searches always included "gradle" as term but the question you linked is indeed fitting. The problem was that the module settings referred to a no longer existing sdkman JDK version. So in this respect Marcin Orlowski was right as well.

Comment: Did you find a fix for this @lathspell? I'm having the same issue and can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: @Franco the project settings pointer to a no longer existing JDK directory

Comment: Interesting @lathspell, I just checked mine and it pointed to a valid JDK, but I had to change it to the Android SDK for it to stop showing those errors. I think the problem is that the project has to point to a valid SDK and it has to be the same SDK that the main module uses.