# Updated intellij messed up Kotlin with 'Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies'

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

Lot's of frustration here. I decided to follow the pop-up prompting an intellij upgrade so it'd stop nagging me.

And now I get a compiler error on certain parts of the code:

```
Cannot access 'java.io.Serializable' which is a supertype of 'kotlin.String'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
```

I can make a new kotlin project with only the following and run it:

```
fun main() {
    println("helloWorld")
}
```

But if I change it to the following it does not compile:

```
fun main() {
    println("hello" to "World")
}
```

[image: modules]

[image]

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_201"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)
```

I'm on windows. I find it very challenging to debug these kind of things. It feels very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64527844/cannot-access-java-io-serializable-which-is-a-supertype-of-kotlin-string-ch) and [this upvoted one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50304263/check-your-module-classpath-for-missing-or-conflicting-dependencies)

Comment: BTW, your project language level is 1.4 instead of 11, like your SDK

Comment: I'll make sure to change it back. I messed around with it trying to fix the issue

Answer (score 3):

I encountered some similar problem on IntelliJ and end up with clicking reload all maven projects button.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It was solved by downloading a jdk and applying it to the project:

Click the plus, select a vendor and download:

[image: download jdk]

And then apply it to the project:

[image]

And rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this problem for many times.  I can't suffer any more torture from Idea. That's the reason I come here for answering.

If your project compile success in maven, but failed in Idea build. You should be confident that you have no fault. It's just a Idea bug!

You can solve this problem by following steps, then rebuild your project.

[image: steps to solve problems]

Answer (score -2):

Invalidate Cache and Restart helped